# how in angularjs to filter list of object by date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

The problem is next: I obtain a list of some objects from DB in format JSON.

```
[{"id":1,"klassBean":{"id":1,"klassName":"11A"},"fname":"Vornic","sname":"Pavel","bdate":1499893200000,"sex":"M","telephone":111,"address":"Soroca"},{"id":2,"klassBean":{"id":1,"klassName":"11A"},"fname":"Gaidarji","sname":"Raisa","bdate":1499893200000,"sex":"F","telephone":222,"address":"Leova"}]
```

Every object contain field type Date. I use standart angular filter to display grid by entered information from some input mapped by `ng-model`. With string type it works fine. The date is convertded in miliseconds, but in input field by datapicker is introduced string.

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="fname" class="form-control" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="sname" class="form-control" /></th>
        <th>
            <select ng-model="sex" class="form-control">
                <option></option>
                <option value="F">F</option>
                <option value="M">M</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="telephone" class="form-control" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="address1" class="form-control" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" ng-model="bdate1 " class="form-control datepicker" /></th>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot data-ng-repeat="pupil in pupilList | filter : {fname : fname, sname : sname, sex:sex, telephone:telephone,address:address1, bdate:bdate2} ">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 10px;">
            <a th:href="@{'/pupil/edit/' + {{pupil.id}}+}">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" title="Vista"> </i>
            </a>
        </td>
        <th>{{pupil.fname}}</th>
        <th>{{pupil.sname}}</th>
        <th>{{pupil.sex}}</th>
        <th>{{pupil.telephone}}</th>
        <th>{{pupil.address}}</th>
        <th>{{pupil.bdate|date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

I formatted date to classic view by date filter, but really it remains in milliseconds, so in controller I made next thing:

```
$scope.$watch('bdate1', function (newValue) {
    if (angular.isUndefined($scope.bdate1)){
        $scope.bdate2=1499893200000;
        return;
    }
    // minus 3 hours timezone
    $scope.bdate2=new Date($scope.bdate1).getTime()-10800000;
});
```

String field bdate1 made date in milliseconds minus 3 hours. This value passed to other variable to $scope.bdate2 and finally compared with it. It works, but code smells. How do you solve this problem ?

Comment: why don't you use `date` filter in angularjs?

Comment: I used filter for display date `<th>{{pupil.bdate|date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</th>`, but introduced data is string `<th><input type="text" ng-model="bdate1 " class="form-control datepicker" /></th>` or what do you mean ?

Comment: Check out my solution below

Answer (score 1):

I use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for anything regarding dates and it makes things soo easy!

```
//time in milliseconds then formats to YYYY-MM-DD
var day = moment(1318781876406).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

It can also handle timezones for you automatically. Check it out: [Moment.js Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but problem consists a little in other thing and not in converting dates )

Comment: "The date is converted in miliseconds, but in input field by datapicker is introduced string." - using moment should be an easy fix. Can you explain what won't work here?

Comment: I must compare `pupil.bdate` which I can't convert with `ng-model="bdate1"` which I can convert. I have converted already string to date in ms, you propose me inverse to convert ms in date. I would like to see some other solution. Thanx.

Comment: You should be able to create a filter for pupil.bdate that converts to date then you can compare the two (or milliseconds if you prefer)

Comment: You are right, but I made smth. like this:    

    `$scope.$watch('bdate1', function (newValue) {
        if (angular.isUndefined($scope.bdate1) || $scope.bdate1==""){
            $scope.bdate2=$scope.bdate1;
            return;
        }
        $scope.bdate2=moment($scope.bdate1).valueOf();
    });`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert the timestamps to the JavaScript date objects, and then applying AngularJS' date filter to them.

```
var json = [ ... ]; // your JSON here

json = json.map(function(item) {
  item.bdate = new Date(item.bdate);
  return item;
});
```

Now, you can simply use AngularJS' date filters to the `bdate` field like this:

```
<th>{{pupil.bdate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</th>
```

Below is a snippet of above code in action.

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.json = [{
      "id": 1,
      "klassBean": {
        "id": 1,
        "klassName": "11A"
      },
      "fname": "Vornic",
      "sname": "Pavel",
      "bdate": 1499893200000,
      "sex": "M",
      "telephone": 111,
      "address": "Soroca"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "klassBean": {
        "id": 1,
        "klassName": "11A"
      },
      "fname": "Gaidarji",
      "sname": "Raisa",
      "bdate": 1499893200000,
      "sex": "F",
      "telephone": 222,
      "address": "Leova"
    }];

    $scope.json = $scope.json.map(function(item) {
      item.bdate = new Date(item.bdate);
      return item;
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in json">
      {{item.bdate | date: 'yyyy-mm-dd'}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you replay, but problem consists of that I can't use filter type filter `data-ng-repeat="pupil in pupilList | filter : {fname : fname, sname : sname, sex:sex, telephone:telephone,address:address1, bdate:bdate2} "`. I can't compare `pupil .bdate` which is date with `<input type="text" ng-model="bdate1 " class="form-control datepicker" />` which is string. Don't forget that I compare also other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Just converted all input fields type date to type string and at last compared two strings

```
$http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: '/ws/getPupils/'+klassName
     }).success(function (data) {
         var values=data;
         angular.forEach(values, function(item) {
            item.bdate =moment(new Date(item.bdate)).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
         });
         $scope.pupilList=data;
     });
```